# Pandas - How to assign different classes to a recurring series without using a loop?

Tags: python, pandas, optimization, series

I have a series with recurring values in pandas dataframe. The first 20 values are given below:

```
# input
[-1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1,  1, -1, 1,  1,  1]
```

Note that -1 indicates the start of a new class while 1 indicates continuation of previous class.
I can change "-1" and "1" to any value for the encoding.
What I want for the output is to be class labels like given below:

```
# output
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5]
```

For now I have done this using a for loop.
I could not find a better way with in-built pandas / python functions.

How do I achieve this without using for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare values by `-1` and use cumulative sum by [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and if first value of Series is `0` subtract `1`:

```
s = pd.Series([-1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, 
                1,  1,  1,  1, -1, 1,  1,  1])
```

---

```
s1 = s.eq(-1).cumsum()
out = s1.sub(1) if s[0] == -1 else s1
```

If always first value is `-1` subtract `1`:

```
out = s.eq(-1).cumsum().sub(1)
```

Comment: I did come across the cumulative sum but for some reason could not figure out that I can compare the series directly with "-1". Thank you for the answer.